# AssertionError at /wel/ Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'NoneTyp

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create an api using django rest framework but facing the above mentioned issue

my models.py code

```
from django.db import models

class React(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    details=models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

and my views.py code

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from . models import *
from rest_framework.response import Response
from . serializer import *


class ReactView(APIView):
    serializer_class = ReactSerializer
    def get(self,request):
        for detail in React.objects.all():
            detail = [{'name':detail.name,'detail':detail.detail}]
            return Response(detail)
        


    def post(self,request):
        serializer=ReactSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception = True):
            serializer.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

If `React.objects.all()` is empty, the `get` method will return `None` and this error will be raised. Just add `return Response({}, status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)` to this method, or anything that makes sense to you application.

```
from rest_framework import status

class ReactView(APIView):
    serializer_class = ReactSerializer
    def get(self,request):
        for detail in React.objects.all():
            detail = [{'name':detail.name,'detail':detail.detail}]
            return Response(detail)
        return Response({}, status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```